# Code not working :: $("#pmhxform input:checkbox:checked").each(function() { var id= $(this).id(); });

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

while submitting a form i want  to get all checkboxes ids which are checked:
here $(this).id() throwing an error.what was the correct code to get ids of all 
checkboxes  which are checked

```
$("#pmhxform input:checkbox:checked").each(function() {
       var id= $(this).id();

});
```

Here `$(this).id()` throwing an error
What was the correct code to get ids of all 
checkboxes  which are checked ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery doesn't have an `id()` function. Use

```
var id = $(this).attr('id');
```

or, more simply:

```
var id = this.id;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `.attr('id')` instead of `.id()`. The last is not a function of jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$( "input[type=checkbox]" ).on( "click",function(){
        alert($(this).attr('id'));      
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/c2TQ3/)

Answer (score 1):

try to change your div's id into a class since id's are unique and you are asking for each()

Answer (score 1):

try too:

```
$( "input[type=checkbox]" ).on( "click",function(){
        alert(this.id);      
});
```